# Custom C# Form Design

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'm kind of stuck on this one, I know it can be done but unsure the steps needed.

I want to create a fully custom User Interface design for an application I'm having to create.  I can change the form background and all that but this is a bit more complex.

An example image is shown below of the kind of change I'm referring to, as you can see its a rather big change compared to the current UI used by most applications.
[image: Example UI image]

Comment: It is likely to be easier in WPF than WinForms. Is this supposted to be WinForm, or can you choose WPF ?

Comment: It's almost impossible with WinForms but very easy with WPF.

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit cynical, but whenever I see a UI like that I immediately think "This app is probably a buggy piece of junk that instead of fixing they decided to cover with gradients and drop shadows"

Comment: what about a third party control toolkit? https://www.devexpress.com/Products/Free/NetOffer/#asp devexpress has some free fancy ones

Comment: although i hate the "you should do this in xyz" when clearly you know what your needs are, maybe you could explain why you need winforms over wpf.  are you using a legacy system like windows 3.1/windows nt?

Comment: and it's not really that impossible to do with winforms, it just would be a whole lot more work, and you would prob get more sleek animations and reuability with wpf than you would with winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't use WPF (why?!), you'll need to create custom classes for all your controls, inheriting and overriding `OnPaint`. This will be a hard job done all with C# code.

[Here is a tutorial](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/building-custom-controls-in-c-part-1/) showing many steps to create custom UI for WinForms.

Comment: outside of my control part of the contract nothing to do with me :(

Comment: Thanks great tutorial site, sadly the site has many 404's but managed to hack and slash my way around :)

Comment: The link does not work for me, I am getting "dns_unresolved_hostname"

Comment: @Matt, unfortunatelly the link seems to be out after so many years. I found another with a similar example and updated the answer.

Comment: @ErickPetrucelli - I know, that happens... thank you for the update!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) which is designed to allow the creation of rich graphical UI applications like the example you gave. It focuses on separating the front end (graphical UI) from the logic behind (which you can code in C#. VB etc.)

It's very different to forms in the way you layout your UI (using a form of XML) but it's all built around the .Net framework which means there will be some level of familiarity.

Check out these links to get started:

http://www.wpftutorial.net/WPFIntroduction.html

http://www.wpf-training-guide.com/

Comment: The 2nd link seems to be broken - can you provide a new one?

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to use WPF as your question doesn't seem to limit itself to using WinForms. It has a lot of the effects I can see in this screenshot out of the box which would be more difficult to implement using WinForms.

Every reuseable control can be created separately and reused later on. WPF is highly extendable and you can compose new controls out of existing controls. You might create the 'up-down' control by using existing button controls, and perhaps you can already find an existing one to suit your needs.

Styling is done separately in WPF, so you can apply your custom style by using templates.

**UPDATE:**

When you **HAVE** to use winforms the easiest solution would be to go for a fixed size window, and let your designer create images for all the buttons and such. ... Old school slicing techniques.

You basically have to decompose the design so you can reuse it as much as possible.
E.g. You will have a couple of button backgrounds depicting their various states. (down/up/hover)
The glow on top of the track information can be stored in a separate image, so it can be applied 'on top' of the text.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured :(